# SQL update with C# with set @variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with SQL query from C#

```
string sql = @"UPDATE tucitelotazky SET  @otazka = @hodnota;";   
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@otazka",otazka);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@hodnota", hodnota);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Variable `@otazka` is selected from a combobox and always returns `OT1`-`OT10` and it is the name of the column in the database.
`@hodnota` contains some text from a textbox.
If I use this SQL query it reports wrong SQL syntax.

Comment: Column name needs to be appended to your query string; it's not a parameter.

Comment: Its cant be given from variable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your combo containing values associated with each of the names.
For example:

```
string column = string.Empty;

switch((int.Parse(cmb.selectedValue))
{
case 1:
column = "OT1"
break;
.
.
.
case 10:
column = "OT10"
break;
}

string sql = @"UPDATE tucitelotazky SET " + column + " = " + "@hodnota;";   
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@hodnota", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hodnota;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Input string was not in the correct format

Comment: Please show us your code so we can analyze what is wrong.

Comment: "UPDATE tucitelotazky SET  " + otazka + " = '" + hodnota + "';";.... there was problem.. i cant believe it was just with that ' :D thank you all

Comment: To avoid this problem, you need to specify the type of the parameter:
cmd.Parameters.Add("@hodnota", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = hodnota;

Answer (score 0):

Column names needs to be appended to the query string, not appended as a parameter.  For example:

```
string sql = @"UPDATE tucitelotazky SET  [your_column_name] = [your_value];";   
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cnn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@hodnota", hodnota);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I think there s only problem with that insert with set.. Because all the time when i entry this. its always entried like 'OT' = 'something' and if i try that in database without ' ' next to the OT it works.. so if i give it to database with string it automaticalyy make ''